# Backbone MVC multiple collections used conditionally

Tags: model-view-controller, backbone.js

I have a plugin that grabs data either from a remote source via ajax or from local source of data stored in memory. I am having a problem getting the collection data to the view for local data (collection is empty, see line 53). The local data is available in the collection as the console.log on line 37 shows the data. Data from remote and local source are JSON of the same structure/hierarchy/values.

**How can I get the data from local source to be available to the view in order to render it in the template?**

```
// pluginname
$.fn.pluginname = function(options) {
var defaults = {
  source: 'external', // external (fetch data from url) or internal (grab data from memory)
},
settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);  

// define the model
item = Backbone.Model.extend();

// define the collection
items = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: item,
  page: settings.page,
  // url to request when fetch() is called
  url: function() {
    return 'http://www.sample.com/feed.json'
  },
  parse: function (response) {
    return response;
  },
  // overwrite the sync method to pass over the same origin policy
  sync: function (method, model, options) {
    var that = this;
    var params = _.extend({
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      url: that.url(),
      processData: false
    }, options);
    // remote source of data
    if (settings.source == 'remote'){
      return $.ajax(params);
      // local source of data (data read from memory via $.data)
    } else if (settings.source == 'local'){
      //return JSON.stringify($('body').data('someid'));
      return console.log(JSON.stringify($('body').data('someid'))); // logs data correctly in console
    };
  }
});

// define the view
itemsView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function () {
    console.log('itemsView initialize')
    _.bindAll(this, 'render');
    // create a collection
    this.collection = new items;
    // fetch the collection and call render() method
    var that = this;
    this.collection.fetch({
      success: function () {
        console.log(that.collection); // fails (returns empty) for json data from local source
        that.render();
      },
      error: function () {
        console.log('collection fetch error'); // does not get logged
      }
    });
  },
  // define template
  template: _.template($('#templateid').html()),
  // render function
  render: function(){
    $(this.el).html(this.template({
      items: this.collection.toJSON()
    }));
  },
});

var app = new itemsView({
  // define the el where the view will render
  el: $('.'+settings.render_selector+'')
});

}; // ends plugin function
```

Comment: Read up on "override sync". The sync function does not return a collection, it should call options.success(someVarWithFetchedData). And if I'm not mistaking, $.ajax(params) returns a jqXHR object.

Comment: @GijsjanB the remote data part works fine. The local data sourced from memory using $.data returns JSON in the collection on line 42 `return console.log(JSON.stringify($('body').data('someid'))); // logs data correctly in console` but from the view, `console.log(this.collection); // returns empty for json data from local source` returns empty object.

Comment: You're right. The sync is supposed to return a jqXHR object! :) My bad. But that is exactly what is going wrong in the local part. You'll have to set the data to the collection or return the data as options.success(data).

Comment: Thanks for your response @GijsjanB. How would I set the data to the collection? or how would I return the data as options.success(data) without using jQuery ajax?

Comment: I just want to pass in JSON stored in memory via $.data as the collection to be used for the view. How would I set up that collection? Right now w/ the code above, that collection can console.log() the data but the view initialize correctly but the collection.fetch seems to be failing w/out any errors. Driving me crazy lol! :)

Answer (score 1):

Return the JSON:

```
} else if (settings.source == 'local'){
    var json = JSON.stringify($('body').data('someid')));
    options.success(json);
};
```

Comment: Thanks again @GijsjanB. The JSON data does go through the collection but the view is unable to access it. From `itemsView`, `this.collection.fetch()` is not succeeding while at the same time not giving an error message. Any ideas?